# Cannot sudo a custom function in a zsh script

Tags: zsh, sudo, password

I want to copy my .dot files (and not .dot directory) in a directory. For this my OS (MacOS) asks me the user password. I created a functions that does that and want to incorporate it in a bigger backup script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/zsh
source ~/.zshrc

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

copy_dotfiles()
{
  MAIN_PATH="/Users/user01/"
  DOTFILE_DIR="${MAIN_PATH}Documents/dot_files"
  echo $DOTFILE_DIR
  mkdir $DOTFILE_DIR
  for f in $MAIN_PATH.[!.]*; do
    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
      echo "$f" is a file
      DOTFILE=`echo $f | sed 's/\/Users\/user01\///g'`
      echo "$DOTFILE" is a file
      cp $f ${DOTFILE_DIR}/${DOTFILE} || exit 1
    elif [[ -d $f ]]; then
      echo "$f" is a dir
      continue
    else
      echo "$f is not valid"
      exit 1
    fi
  done
}

sudo copy_dotfiles || exit 1
```

However when I run the script I get this:

```
sudo: copy_dotfiles: command not found
```

Comment: why does your script source .zshrc? That seems like an unusual choice, quite frankly, even a bad idea?

Comment: `copy_dotfiles_and_directories` doesn't appear in your script, so you're running a different script than you're showing us here.

Comment: by the way, why so complicated – the functionality of your whole script seems to be lie in using the right globbing parameters, and you already seem to have understood that! `sudo cp /Users/user01/.*(.) /Users/user01/Documents/dot_files/` would do the same.

Comment: No related to the question, but a hint on using `sed` and strings with slashes: use a different separator: `sed 's#/Users/user01/#g'` for example, it's clearer and less prone to errors.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Hashmark (`#`) is a tricky suggestion because when unquoted (not in your example, but easy to do it otherwise) it simply turns the rest of the line into a comment. You also seem to have missed the third `#` for the `s` operator, so eg. `sed 's@/Users/user01/@@g'`

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` is not a shell function – it's a separate executable that executes executables :)

So, it can't run a shell function. It can run a shell script, though! So, if you want this to work, omit the `sudo` from this script, and run the whole script through sudo.

You **definitely** should remove your `source ~/.zshrc`, either way, but *especially* when running the script as root.

Answer (score 0):

Inline comments on that code:

> ```
> #!/bin/zsh
> source ~/.zshrc
> ```

Why would you source the invoking user's interactive shell customisation file in a script? That makes no sense.

> ```
> set -o errexit
> ```

You set `errexit`, but then you (try to) use `somefunction || ...` which cancels the effect of `errexit`.

> ```
> set -o nounset
> set -o pipefail
> ```

Not that you can also do `set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail` like in any POSIX shell or `setopt errexit nounset pipefail`

> ```
> copy_dotfiles()
> {
>   MAIN_PATH="/Users/user01/"
>   DOTFILE_DIR="${MAIN_PATH}Documents/dot_files"
> ```

Variable with all-uppercase names are usually used for environment variables or variables with a glob scope. Setting a global variable with a fixed value in a function seems odd.

```
copy_dotfiles() { # Arg: username
  local target_dir=~$1/Documents/dot_files
```

For  `copy_dotfiles` to take the username as argument and set a  local variable with the destination directory in their home directory would make more sense.

Not much point defining a function that doesn't target arguments

> ```
>   echo $DOTFILE_DIR
> ```

Beware `echo` does transformation on its arguments before printing. Better yo use: `print -r -- $DOTFILE_DIR` or `printf '%s\n' $DOTFILE_DIR`

> ```
>   mkdir $DOTFILE_DIR
> ```

If you run it as `root`, the new directory will be created with `root` as its user instead of the target user. You're not checking the exit status of `mkdir` and `errexit` is cancelled if the exit status of the function is  being handled, so the rest of the code could end up being executed in `mkdir` fails. That could have dramatic consequences like if the user happens to have created `~/Documents/dot_files` already as a symlink to some sensitive system are, or as a directory containing files with  symlinks to sensitive files such as `/etc/shadow`, `/root/.bashrc`...

Also as a general principle `cmd $anything_dynamic` should be `cmd -- $anything_dynamic` to make sure `$anything_dynamic` is not treated as an option if it happens to start with a `-`.

> ```
>   for f in $MAIN_PATH.[!.]*; do
> ```

It's more common for pathname/dir variables to be defined as the path to a directory and to use `$dir/file-within` instead of having a trailing `/` in the variable value  and do `${dir}file-within`.

Also zsh globs never include `.` nor `..`, `^` is preferred over `!` in zsh for set negation, and `.[!.]*` while it would exclude `.` and `..` would also exclude `..file` files.

You'd also likely want to use the `N` glob qualifier to allow the list to be empty and declare `f` local:

```
local f
for f in $source_dir/.*(N); do
```

> ```
>     if [[ -f $f ]]; then
>       echo "$f" is a file
> ```

More like `print -r -- $f is a regular file or symlink to regular file`.

Also `zsh` globs can select files by type, so you don't need  to use `[[...]]` in a loop here.

> ```
>       DOTFILE=`echo $f | sed 's/\/Users\/user01\///g'`
>       echo "$DOTFILE" is a file
>       cp $f ${DOTFILE_DIR}/${DOTFILE} || exit 1
> ```

Modifying file paths with `sed` or any other text utility is wrong in general as `sed` is line-based and file paths can be made of several lines. `zsh` has text substitution operators builtin (including the `${var/pattern/replacement}` from ksh and `$var:s/string/replacement/` from csh) and `$var:t` to get the tail of a path  but  here, you don't need to do any substitution as `cp` can do both *copy-to* and *copy-into*.

```
cp -- $f $target_dir/
```

Would copy `$f` into the directory whose path  is stored in `$target_dir`.

But again, if run as root, that  would be  verify dangerous.

> ```
>     elif [[ -d $f ]]; then
>       echo "$f" is a dir
>       continue
>     else
>       echo "$f is not valid"
>       exit 1
>     fi
>   done
> }
>
> sudo copy_dotfiles || exit 1
> ```

`sudo` is a external command that takes the name or path of a command file to execute. It can't take function names from any shell or other programming language.

You could tell it to execute a shell, and that  shell define and invoke a function, which here you could do with:

```
exec sudo zsh -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail -c '
  '"$(typeset -f -- copy_dotfile)"'
  "$0" "$@"' copy_dotfile "$@"
```

But here, since the whole script is just that function, you might as well invoke it as root or the script try to re-execute itself as root if it's not super-user:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o nounset

# reexecute as root if effecive uid is not 0 (not privileged).
(( EUID == 0 )) || exec sudo -u root -- "$0" "$@"

user=${1?}

ERRNO=0 USERNAME=$user # drop privileges by switching all uids and gids
                       # to those of the target user
(( ERRNO )) && exit 1 # abort if we couldn't drop privileges

# cd to the source directory
cd -P -- ~$user || exit

# hidden regular (.) files.
dotfiles=( .*(N.) )

destdir=Documents/dot_files
mkdir -p -- $destdir || exit

if (( $#dotfiles )) exec cp -pP -- $dotfiles $destdir/
```

(untested)